# PHP class returns "this page isn't working" without echo

Tags: php, class

I've put the Google Calendar API inside a wrapper class

```
Class cl_calendar
{
private $db;
private $google_client;
private $google_service;
private $calendar_id;

public function __construct($calendar_id = 'primary')
{   $this->db = new cl_database();

    // ...

    $this->do_initialise();
}

public function do_initialise()
{   require_once '../plugins/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/autoload.php';

    $this->google_client = $this->getClient();
    $this->google_service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->google_client);
}

private function getClient()
{   $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setAuthConfig('../plugins/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/client_secret.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    $credentialsPath = $this->expandHomeDirectory('../plugins/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/credentials.json');
    if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim('...');

        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

        if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
        printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
    }
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}

private function expandHomeDirectory($path)
{   $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
    if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
        $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
    }
    return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

public function do_cleanup_deleted_events() {
    $qry = 'select ...';
    $sql = $this->db->do_select($qry);

    foreach ($sql as $row) {
        $event = $this->google_service->events->get($this->calendar_id, $row['calendar_id']);

        if ($event) {
            if ($event['status'] == 'cancelled') {   // DELETED
                $qry = 'update ...';
                $this->db->do_update($qry);
            }
        }
    }

    echo 'ok';

    return true;
}
}
```

So far so good. This code works perfectly (left out some unnecessary code and keys for Google API.

But ... the browser returns "This page isn't working" when I remove the "echo 'ok';" line in the 'do_cleanup_deleted_events()' method. Probably something obvious but I can't understand why this is.

My code to create the class and run the method:

```
require_once('../logic/calendar.class.php');
$calendar = new cl_calendar('primary');
$calendar->do_cleanup_deleted_events();
```

Comment: Do you get an actual error, or is this maybe just your browser’s way of telling you that there wasn’t anything returned that could be displayed? Does your script create any actual output without that echo?

Comment: The script doesn't output anything, so it should be a blank page.

Comment: Check what gets actually returned in the browser devtools network panel. Is the status code 200, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Well, sort of.

So the event I'm looking for doesn't exist anymore in that calendar. Hence the error. When I put the code in a try catch, it solves the problem.

However, removing the try catch and putting an "echo 'ok';" also "solves" the problem. I find it weird that the error doesn't persist when the echo is placed. No idea why this is.